# Configure gradle distribution task

Tags: gradle

I am using the `application` plugin and would like to do something like this:

**build.gradle**

```
apply from: 'common.gradle'

folder1Files = []
folder1Files << "file1.txt"
folder1Files << "file2.txt"
```

**common.gradle**

```
distributions {
  main {
    contents {
      into ("folder1") { from(folder1Files) }
    }
  }
}
```

I understand that this can be done by simply adding the `apply from` after the variable definitions but I was wondering whether there is a more 'bullet proof'/correct way?

In other words, how can I define variables for configuring the distribution task before it is configured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it's possible but You need to exchange variables via `project` instance. Try:

**common.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'application'

project.ext.folder1Files = []

distributions {
  main {
    contents {
      into ("folder1") { from(folder1Files) }
    }
  }
}
```

**build.gradle**

```
apply from: 'common.gradle'

project.folder1Files << "file1.txt"
project.folder1Files << "file2.txt"
```

Comment: This still requires correct order though is less shouting out 'hack!'.

Comment: Another option I thought about (maybe overkill) was to create a plugin which is responsible for the configuration and adding everything to 'project' and then make the 'installDist' task dependent on this

Comment: It's not an overkill. It seems to be a good idea because there's no order problem.

Comment: As long as plugin is added before the `apply from` I guess. But here I will also have the problem that I can't add the plugin in `common.gradle` (according to various posts, defining buildscript dependency, plugins in external file doesnt work) so it adds a lot of code to `build.gradle` while ideally I would have wanted this in common.gradle.

Comment: Would need to test it, before commenting :/